# How to distinguish between mouseenter and tap events?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

If you have a `mouseenter` event, touch-enabled devices will trigger this event when user taps the element.

How to distinguish between a genuine (physical) mouse enter event and a tap (mouse enter simulation)?

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the user is visiting your website from a mobile device:

```
if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) 
    // do something
else
    // do something else
```